# execute multiple functions in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have large number of functions and every of them should load url from the list and do some operations. I need all functions to do do in parallel if it's possible and each functions should parallely load urls from the list. I have some code here, but I am not sure if it does what I metioned or mabye this can be done simpler? Thank you

```
class Multi(object):


    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, urls_func1, urls_func2):
        """ Initialize class with list of urls """
        self.urls_func1 = urls_func1
        self.urls_func2 = urls_func2 
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def func1(self, url, que):
        "do something"
        que.put(result_func1)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def func2(self, url, que):
        "do something"
        que.put(result_func2)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------      
    def run(self):

        "For func1"
        jobs = []
        queue1=[]        
        for url in urls_func1:
            queue1.append(Queue())
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.func1, args=(url,queue1[len(jobs)],))
            jobs.append(process)
            process.start()
        for job in jobs:
            job.join()

        "For func2"
        jobs = []
        queue2=[]      
        for url in urls_func1:
            queue2.append(Queue())
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.func2, args=(url,queue2[len(jobs)],))
            jobs.append(process)
            process.start()
        for job in jobs:
            job.join()



        return result_func1, result_func2

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------


if __name__ == "__main__":

    urls_for_func1=['www.google.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.google.com']
    urls_for_func2=['www.google.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.google.com']
    a,b=(Multi(urls_for_func1, urls_for_func2).run())
```

EDIT: Correction of variable names

Comment: "i am not sure if it does what i metioned [sic]"? Have you even tried it?

Comment: It is working of course, just does it work in parallel everything?

Comment: anyone have suggestion?

Comment: If it is faster than the case with only one thread then it is parallel.

Comment: Have a look at [concurrent.futures](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures).

Comment: I am new to multiprocessing, can you help me by modifying code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download multiple urls concurrently while limiting the total number of parallel jobs using a thread pool:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads

def func1(url):
    # download url here
    return url, "result", None

def func2(url):
    # do something with the url unsuccessfully
    return url, None, "describe the error"

pool = Pool(20) # no more than 20 concurrent connections
results_for_func1 = pool.map(func1, urls_func1) # it blocks until done
results_for_func2 = pool.map(func2, urls_func2)
```

Comment: Sabastian, can you please tell me what should i do if i want (for example), both functions to execute parallel? Lets say they bouth open list of urls parallely? Thanks for code

Comment: @Jovan: `async_result = pool.map_async(f, args)` returns immediately. To get result later: `r = async_result.get()`.

Comment: @Sabastian: this pool.map is just perfect, mabye i didnt get it, are you suggesting my to use pool.map_async(f, args) on functions also? This example is just great, but one little more if its possible... How to run functions in parallel? This code runs one function multiple times(parallel) for the list of arguments... How to this with functions? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jovan: yes, use `.map_async()` to run the functions in parallel. To run two different functions, call it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `multiprocessing` because your workload is network-bound.

`threading` is easier and scales better, to thousands (your RAM / 8 MB).

If you need more scale than this, use `greenlet` (easy) or twisted (hardcore)

Comment: Can you put some example code, please?